# edit middle of string in react always goes to the end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, material-ui

i have a material-ui input in my reactJS app.
everything is fine. but when i try to edit (add or modify) the text in the middle of the string, the cursor always goes to the end of the string after every letter i put.

i assume it's because of the rerender the component after every input change
so if i won't enter the value attribute it will work. but i do want to write it the react way...

any suggestions?

```
<input value={this.props.value} onChange={this.props.onChange}/>
```

Comment: That is a known bug for years. Try to use a textfield, which should fix that.

Comment: tried. didn't fix the problem

Comment: Can you create a codepen to reproduce that ? So we can check it out ?

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using [controlled inputs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components). That will fix the jumping cursor problem and is the React way.

The jumping is caused by the re-render. I assume that `this.props.onChange` updates a state of the parent component and passes it to this component? It is better to maintain the state of the input in the same component and call the parents chance function from there.

Comment: Because of rerendering parent component then input will loose focus because the component will fully rerendered